# Accessing list of destinations in ActiveMQ with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I want to retrieve a list/set of available topics & queues from ActiveMQ, with the use of Spring Boot. I've been able to find how this is done via plain Java (with the use of an ActiveMQConnectionFactory) and I've looked around the documentation of Springs (connection) factories but I cannot find where/how to find a list of destinations.

Comment: if you use apache-camel, you cna use camelcontext to get endpoints

Comment: @pvpkiran I am not using apache-camel, the project is pure spring-boot and ActiveMQ.

Comment: If you have found how to retrieve that using `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` what is wrong with that? Spring Boot doesn't expose a service that shows the available destinations.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I've been unable to find if/where I can access the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` which gets created by Spring boot.

Comment: Just inject it in one of your bean